# Best practices for lock (or Enter/Exit) in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I have a measuring instrument object:

```
public class Instrument
{
  public double Measure() 
  { 
    return 0; 
  }
}
```

I have a device that needs to do some measuring:

```
public class Device
{
  public Instrument MeasuringInstrument { get; set; }
  public void DoMeasuring()
  {
    var result = this.MeasuringInstrument.Measure();
  }
}
```

The measuring instrument can only operate on one device at a time, yet many devices may use the same instrument. I'm new to threading, and from what I understand, both of the following solutions have caveats.

```
public class Instrument
{
  public double Measure() 
  { 
    lock(this)
    {
      return 0; 
    }
  }
}

public class Device
{
  public Instrument MeasuringInstrument { get; set; }
  public void DoMeasuring()
  {
    lock(this.MeasurementInstrument)
    {
      var result = this.MeasuringInstrument.Measure();
    }
  }
}
```

I've read it's best to lock on private objects, but I don't know how to do that while still allowing the MeasuringInstrument to be get/set on the Device. Any suggestions?

Thanks much,
Ken

Comment: for future generations: Managed Threading Best Practices http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1c9txz50(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the usual pattern is to create your own private `object` just for locking in the case where the obvious choice might be exposed outside of the class, for example:

```
public class Instrument
{
    private object thisLock = new object();

    public double Measure() 
    { 
        lock(this.thisLock)
        {
            return 0; 
        }
    }
}

public class Device
{
    public Instrument MeasuringInstrument { get; set; }
    private object measuringInstrumentLock = new object();

    public void DoMeasuring()
    {
        lock(this.measuringInstrumentLock)
        {
            var result = this.MeasuringInstrument.Measure();
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I suspect that you only need one of those two locks (either the one in `DoMeasuring` or the one in `Measure`) although that does depend on the missing bits.

Comment: The second lock in Device is not required.

Comment: hii.. I am new in threading and locking... Use lock on private objects.. its fine. But please tell me what actually "lock" do. I mean if there are 10 objects of Instrument class then every object would have its own copy of Measure(). Now, what is the purpose of lock?

Answer (score 5):

if your `instrument` is used by multiple `devices` the best practice is to set `lock` in your `instrument` class. so the fist solution works better.

but its better to create a new lock object and use it in `instrument` class.

```
public class Instrument
{
  Object lockKey = new Object();
  public double Measure() 
  { 
    lock(lockKey)
    {
      return 0; 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @frazin. I agree but a better answer would inlude why its better